# How to pass and retrieve data from angularjs controller to a struts action

Tags: angularjs, struts2

**Angular js Controller**

```
var data = {"username" : $scope.username,"password" : $scope.password};

    $scope.sign = function($location, $window, $rootScope) {
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/Newproject/getin.action',
            params : {value:data},
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }).success(function(data) {

        });
```

**struts.xml(action)**

```
      <action name="getin" class="com.cibin.SignInAction">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/welcome.home

            <param name="value">value</param></result>

        <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/index.jsp</result>
        <result name="loginpage">/index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**SignInAction.java**

```
public String execute() {

    String contactJsonData = request.getParameter("value");
    System.out.print(contactJsonData);

    return "success";
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; AngularJS doesn't care what the back end is. Are you asking how to return JSON using S2? (E.g., use the JSON or REST plugins.)

Comment: If you send json to the action make sure you can read it on the backend, on the other hand you should produce json object and return it back to the angular controller. Struts2 can handle both cases flawlessly.